# How to check if a variable is empty in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my app, I want to check if a string variable is empty.

I've handled it as follows,

```
 if ((Name == null) || (Name == ""))
  {
     //Handled
  }
```

But it passes this condition, if the value is given as "  "(whitespace).
How can i detect if the variable contains only whitespaces??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check if it is null and `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`
 to chack for whitespace!! For your case `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Name)`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
{
    //Handled
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name)
```

And [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article about it

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check null or empty and `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check null or whitespace